# 100% Height Div on iPad

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

I am working on a responsive website using the Skeleton Grid and have a left floated navigation bar div that is 100% height of the browser window.  It works in all browsers I've tested except for mobile safari on the iPad.  In mobile safari the navigation div is 100% of the viewport, but when you scroll down on the page the div does not stretch to the bottom of the content.  [See image below].

How do I make it so that the div is 100% height on the iPad, not just 100% of the viewport?

**Dev Site:** http://www.id8agency.com/jeremiah

**Screenshot of the problem:** http://www.id8agency.com/jeremiah/jeremiah.png *(as you can see the white bar on the left does not stretch to the bottom of the page once you scroll)*

**How it should look:** id8agency.com/jeremiah/jeremiah1.png *(sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links)*

**Things I've tried:**

- Set height and min-height to 110% (works, but creates a scroll bar on
  the desktop site)
- Set height to height of content (works, but not all pages will be the
  same length, so creates a scrollbar on some pages where content is
  shorter)
- Set position:absolute and and position bottom:0px (doesn't work,
  positions the div at the bottom of the viewport, not the bottom of the page)
- Set meta viewport tag to height=device-height and height=1000 (breaks
  the responsive functionality of the website)

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try having the `.navigation` element be `position: fixed;` and then place the the content in the right in its own wrapper (something like `.content-right`).

Then set these properties on the `.content-right` element include a media query "reset" for when everything goes to one column (XXX is the breakpoint):

```
.content-right {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

@media screen (max-width: XXX){
  .content-right {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great, simple solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put on outer div and apply the background of the sidebar (sliced so it can be repeated on the y axis) to it and repeat-y? 
It will expand up to the content end and when you don't need it anymore, you can remove the background from the media queries.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, that is what I'm doing now. There is currently a div that has the white as a background that repeats a 1x1 image. On the iPad though, the div does not scroll the full 100% of the content of the page, it only goes to the bottom of the viewport. If I misunderstood your suggestion please let me know.

Comment: No I mean an outer div that holds the left and the right section, and repeat the background ONLY wit repeat-y, not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem also appears when I set my desktop browser viewport to a small height. I think the problem is, that all the 100%-heights here are relative to the viewport, and I think you want the navigation bar to be the height of the content, not the viewport.

But possible solutions would be to set a faux column on the #container-element (see http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns). 
Another possibility would be to measure the height of the #container-element with jquery and assign it to the navigation-bar. Something like:

```
var containerHeight = $('#container').height();
$('#navigation-container').css('height',containerHeight);
```

(I haven't checked if it works, but I think it should.)